# Calculator application including keyboard input in java swing

Tags: java, swing, calculator, key-bindings, glasspane

I have a calculator application in java swing, which is working properly with mouse click input. Now I want it to read input using keyboard button stroke. I had heard about the **glass pane** in java tutorial, but i need to know any other simple method to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`KeyPadPanel`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel) is an example that uses [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for numeric entry.

Comment: More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16081811/230513) on evaluating expressions.