# How to change font size of JButton according to its size?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jbutton

I have a java application - a calculator. I want to resize font of buttons dynamically with resizing the window of the app. How to implement it?

My idea is using ComponentEvents. I have initial size of the window of application and initial fonts' sizes. I want to change font size according to button's size, affected by window size change. The problem is how to use the ratio [initial window size] / [initial font size] in the overriden method? The ratio is different for each font.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        super("Test");

        JPanel cPane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        cPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        MyButton sampleButton = new MyButton("Sample text");
        sampleButton.setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        MyButton a, b, c, d;
        a = new MyButton("a");
        b = new MyButton("b");
        c = new MyButton("c");
        d = new MyButton("d");




        cPane.add(a, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        cPane.add(b, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        cPane.add(c, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        cPane.add(d, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        cPane.add(sampleButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Main();
    }

    class MyButton extends JButton implements ComponentListener {
        public MyButton(String title) {
            super(title);
        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            //resizing font
        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not tried this myself, but I imagine that I'd look at I'd look at possibly using FontMetrics. What have you tried so far, and how isn't it working? It's always good to attempt these things first, and to show us your attempts.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels upd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See how you go with this code using `GlyphVector` to determine the largest `Font` that will fit.

- The GUI was a little shaky unless there was a delay between setting the frame visible and adding the `ComponentListener`.  I solved that by delaying adding the listener using a single shot Swing `Timer`.
- Is is based on [`Calculet`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556) which is a fully functioning (if simple) calculator using the `ScriptEngine`.

[image: Initial]

[image: Bigger]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.script.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

class SwingCalculator implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    JTextField io;
    ScriptEngine engine;
    ArrayList<JButton> controls;
    final BufferedImage textImage = new BufferedImage(
            100, 100,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    public int getMaxFontSizeForControls() {
        Graphics2D g = textImage.createGraphics();
        FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
        int maxSize = 500;
        for (JButton b : controls) {
            // skip the = button..
            if (!b.getText().equals("=")) {
                int max = getMaxFontSizeForControl(b, frc);
                if (maxSize > max) {
                    maxSize = max;
                }
            }
        }
        g.dispose();
        return maxSize;
    }

    public int getMaxFontSizeForControl(JButton button, FontRenderContext frc) {
        Rectangle r = button.getBounds();
        Insets m = button.getMargin();
        Insets i = button.getBorder().getBorderInsets(button);
        Rectangle viewableArea = new Rectangle(
                r.width - 
                (m.right + m.left + i.left + i.right),
                r.height - 
                (m.top + m.bottom + i.top + i.bottom)
                );
        Font font = button.getFont();
        int size = 1;
        boolean tooBig = false;
        while (!tooBig) {
            Font f = font.deriveFont((float) size);
            GlyphVector gv = f.createGlyphVector(frc, button.getText());
            Rectangle2D box = gv.getVisualBounds();
            if (box.getHeight() > viewableArea.getHeight()
                    || box.getWidth() > viewableArea.getWidth()) {
                tooBig = true;
                size--;
            }
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    }

    SwingCalculator() {
        // obtain a reference to the JS engine
        engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");

        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
        controls = new ArrayList<JButton>();

        JPanel text = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 3, 3));
        gui.add(text, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        io = new JTextField(15);
        Font font = io.getFont();
        font = font.deriveFont(font.getSize() * 1.7f);
        io.setFont(font);
        io.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.TRAILING);
        io.setFocusable(false);
        text.add(io);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 2, 2));
        gui.add(buttons, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        addButton(buttons, "7");
        addButton(buttons, "8");
        addButton(buttons, "9");
        addButton(buttons, "/");

        addButton(buttons, "4");
        addButton(buttons, "5");
        addButton(buttons, "6");
        addButton(buttons, "*");

        addButton(buttons, "1");
        addButton(buttons, "2");
        addButton(buttons, "3");
        addButton(buttons, "-");

        addButton(buttons, "0");
        addButton(buttons, ".");
        addButton(buttons, "C");
        addButton(buttons, "+");

        JButton equals = new JButton("=");
        equals.addKeyListener(this);
        controls.add(equals);
        equals.addActionListener(this);
        gui.add(equals, BorderLayout.EAST);

        gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Calculet");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(gui);
        f.pack();
        f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);

        final ComponentListener cl = new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                int ii = getMaxFontSizeForControls();
                for (JButton b : controls) {
                    if (!b.getText().equals("=")) {
                        b.setFont(b.getFont().deriveFont((float) ii));
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                f.addComponentListener(cl);
            }
        };
        Timer t = new Timer(500, al);
        t.setRepeats(false);
        t.start();
    }

    public void addButton(Container c, String text) {
        JButton b = new JButton(text);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        b.addKeyListener(this);
        controls.add(b);
        c.add(b);
    }

    public void calculateResult() {
        try {
            Object result = engine.eval(io.getText());
            if (result == null) {
                io.setText("Output was 'null'");
            } else {
                io.setText(result.toString());
            }
        } catch (ScriptException se) {
            io.setText(se.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String command = ae.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("C")) {
            io.setText("");
        } else if (command.equals("=")) {
            calculateResult();
        } else {
            io.setText(io.getText() + command);
        }
    }

    private JButton getButton(String text) {
        for (JButton button : controls) {
            String s = button.getText();
            if (text.endsWith(s)
                    || (s.equals("=")
                    && (text.equals("Equals") || text.equals("Enter")))) {

                return button;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * START - Because I hate mice.
     */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        String s = ke.getKeyText(ke.getKeyCode());
        JButton b = getButton(s);
        if (b != null) {
            b.requestFocusInWindow();
            b.doClick();
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SwingCalculator();
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But resizing behavior is strange. Here are 
[JAR](http://rghost.ru/download/private/51608964/e2e964eee2e616106a7e48fb57bf6e74/6c48c8e585d7c58030265bc28d7c3e2d5ea5f2a7/Calc.jar) and 
[Source](http://pastebin.com/mRPF73WU) (Java 8).
Please review, if you'll have time.

Comment: Looks good on Mac OS X; invoke `cl.componentResized(null)` after `setVisible(true)` to get a resized initial display; see also the key binding  alternative cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10099809/230513); previously up-voted.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the approaches shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014525/230513). The former uses an available [`JComponent.sizeVariant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html).

[image: image1]

The latter cites an example using `FontMentrics`.

[image: image2]

Or `TextLayout`.

[image: image3]